# What does a stack trace including Namespace.ClassName.<MethodName>b__f mean?

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I have an error log from a user with a stack trace that I don't fully understand. Here's how it looks

```
Stack Trace:
   at ...Presenters.Forms.PresenterHome.<GetCounts>b__f(IActivityItem activityItem)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ...Presenters.Forms.PresenterHome.GetCounts(Int32& completeCount, Int32& incompleteCount)
   at ...Presenters.Forms.PresenterHome.UpdateSummaryPanel()
   .....
```

(I have removed the start of some namespaces to protect client's identity)

The part I don't understand is `<GetCounts>b__f(...)` and why it is called after `Enumerable.Count[...](...)`. I assume it has something to do with the `Count` predicate but I can't quite decipher this.

If it helps the exception is an `InvalidCastException`. Here is some of the code involved (slightly modified to protect identity).

```
void UpdateSummaryPanel()
{
    int completeCount;
    int incompleteCount;
    GetCounts(out completeCount, out incompleteCount);
    ...
}

private void GetCounts(
    out int completeCount, 
    out int incompleteCount)
{
    incompleteCount = _applicationContext.ActivityItems.Count(
        activityItem => activityItem.ActivityType == ActivityTypes.Foo
                        && ((FooActivity) activityItem).Status != CaptureStatus.Bar);

    // similar code for other count
}
```

For what it's worth I'm pretty sure I know what's causing the error (ie where the bad cast is) but what I'm really curious about is that `<GetCounts>b__f(...)` member in the stack trace.

Comment: Looks like autogenerated code. Typical sources for that are lambdas, `yield`-iterators, and C#5's `async`-methods. In your case it's clearly the lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up your assembly with Reflector, dotPeek etc, you'll see that the compiler has put the logic for your lambda expression inside `GetCounts` into another method - in this case `<GetCounts>b__f`. This is entirely normal for lambda expressions and anonymous methods - and some other C# features (iterator blocks, anonymous types, automatically implemented methods etc) also create members for you automatically.

The angle-brackets in the name are a good indication of it being compiler-generated: the compiler uses an *unspeakable name* - one which isn't a valid identifier - to make sure that not only will there not be any collisions with your other members, but you'll also never be able to refer to these "hidden" members within your code.

Comment: Thanks Jon! (love your books, especially your F# one with Tomas Petricek)

Comment: @MartinDoms: It's embarrassing that I really don't know F# - Tomas did almost all the work on that one :)

Comment: I mentally skip over the async / await keywords so it didn't click for me at first why I wasn't seeing my error as ClassName.MethodName().  Instead I was seeing ClassName.<MethodName>d__123.MoveNext().  I realized if your code is using the async / await approach, the compiler has to auto-generate the wrapper code to support that functionality.  So it then made sense.

Answer (score 1):

It means it is within something that the compiler generated, in this case being an anonymous delegate. More specifically, the compiler is generating a method named `<GetCounts>b__f` on your type.